# error c0000374, has triggered a breakpoint

Tags: c++

In the function, in the middle of  'while' loop (not in the first loop), I get an error: 'has triggered a breakpoint.' in another computer the error does not appear.

'product' is a struct I created
the error is in line 'temp = (product*)malloc(sizeof(product));'
when I press continue the next error appears:
'Unhandled exception at 0x777C8529 (ntdll.dll) in ConsoleApplication39.exe: 0xC0000374: A heap has been corrupted (parameters: 0x778058A0).'

this is the code of the function:

```
product* CreateProducts(product *head, FILE* out)
{
    char tempname[100];
    FILE* in = fopen("Manot.txt", "r");
    if (in == NULL)
        GetLost("can't open the file");
    product *temp;
    temp = (product*)malloc(sizeof(product));
    if (temp == NULL)
    {
        freelist(head);
        GetLost("error! not enough memory");
    }

    while (fscanf(in, "%s%d%d %c", tempname, &(temp->quantity), &(temp->price), &(temp->primium)) != EOF)
    {
        temp->next = head;
        head = temp;
        if (head->quantity < 0 || head->price<0)
            fprintf(out, "quantity and price should be positive\n");
        else {
            head->productname = (char*)malloc(sizeof(strlen(tempname) + 1));
            if (head->productname == NULL)
            {
                freelist(head);
                GetLost("error! not enough memory");
            }
            strcpy(head->productname, tempname);
            temp = (product*)malloc(sizeof(product));
            if (temp == NULL)
            {
                freelist(head);
                GetLost("error! not enough memory");
            }

        }
    }

    fprintf(out, "the kitchen was created\n");
    return head;
}
```

Comment: Nothing in the above code looks like `C++` reconsider the question tag.

Comment: `sizeof(strlen(tempname) + 1)` is a very weird amount of memory to reserve (either 4 or 8 bytes). If your `tempname` happens to contain more characters, your heap will indeed be corrupted. The fix is to use `malloc(strlen(tempname) + 1)` to reserve the memory OR `strdup` to allocate a cloned string OR using memory-safe containers like `std::string`

Comment: note that `sizeof()` is a compile time constant.

Comment: It is a very nasty mishap. Occurs when you call malloc or free, at that time the OS can detect that the heap got corrupted. Exactly when you don't know, just earlier by code that ran since the last time you did something with the heap. Buffer overflow is the most typical cause. There are other bugs visible in this snippet, product->next won't be initialized correctly and that by itself can cause plenty of misery.